# remove duplicates in first 2 dimension in a matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, of size 3XN. Each column in the matrix is a 3d point. I want to
remove duplicates, and I only care about duplicates in the first 2 dimensions. 
If a duplicate point exists (i.e. x,y are identical), I would like to choose the one with the highest value in the 3rd dimension (the z-coordinate).
for example:
(first 2 dimensions are first 2 rows)

```
M = [ 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 ;
      4 4 4 6 6 3 2 2 ;
      3 4 5 3 4 5 7 8 ];
          ^ ^ ^ ^   ^
```

I would like to get:

```
Res = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ;
       4 6 6 3 2 ;
       5 3 4 5 8]
```

I need it to work as fast as possible since the matrix is very big. So, if possible with out sorting. I'm looking for a matlab "shortcut" to do this, without looping or sorting.
Thanks
matlabit

Answer (score 3):

That can be easily and efficiently done with `accumarray`:

```
% - choose pairs of row/column indices - first two rows of M
% - accumulate using MAX of the values in the third row - this step removes the duplicates
res = accumarray(M(1:2,:)', M(3,:)', [], @max);

% i/j indices of non-zero entries in the result matrix are
% the unique index pairs, and the value is the maximum third row
% value for all duplicates
[i, j, v] = find(res);

% construct the result matrix
[i j v]'


ans =

 5     4     1     2     3
 2     3     4     6     6
 8     5     5     3     4
```

If your indices are really large and you can not create the matrix `res` for memory reasons, you can use sparse version of the `accumarray` function - it creates a sparse matrix, which only stores the non-zero entries. The rest remains the same:

```
res = accumarray(M(1:2,:)', M(3,:)', [], @max, 0, true);
```

Comment: Thats a really cool solution, but the problem is that not always my values are integers, they can also be floats... but still, this solution was very educating ! :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scan your first 2 rows and insert the elements into a `max-heap`. While inserting, you can check on the fly if the element already exists (don't insert it into the heap in this case). If it exists, compare it with current maximum and set as maximum if needed. The final maximum is the result you seek.

Complexity of building a heap is `O(n)` and checks for maximum do not breach this boundary.
Hence the total time complexity is `O(n)`, compared to the `O(nlogn)` if using sorting. An additional `O(n)` space will be required as well.

Comment: I'd love to see some Matlab code that implements this. It is an interesting problem, since I don't think Matlab has any native methods for working with heaps, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @ColinTBowers I have no idea actually. However since the OP speaks about the possibility of sorting in Matlab, I think it's not conceptually different from inserting into heap as far as Matlab concerns. I.e., it requires a simple data structure and algorithm (it's also possible to implement heap with a standard array that surely exists in Matlab).

Comment: Hi guys, with sorting, and inspiration from that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946845/group-by-in-matlab, m = sortrows(m');  grpstats(m,m(:,1:2), {'max'}), works, i think :-)

Comment: And here is a Matlab code with heap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748322/heapsort-in-matlab

Comment: but, I still think a better solution should exists ... than the grpstats, (not the heap :-))